# Выполнить блок кода заново, после нажатия одной из кнопок

Tags: java, android

Имеется данный код:

```
final int i =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
final int j =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
switch (i){
    case 1:colorText.setText(R.string.Red); break;
    case 2:colorText.setText(R.string.Green); break;
    case 3:colorText.setText(R.string.Blue); break;
    case 4:colorText.setText(R.string.Yellow);
}
switch (j){
    case 1:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));break;
    case 2:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));break;
    case 3:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));break;
    case 4:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
}

buttontrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (i==j){
            Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "Nice!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "So bad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
buttonfalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (i!=j){
            Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "Nice!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "So bad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Необходимо чтобы после нажатия одной из кнопок данный код начал выполняться заново.

Comment: В чем сложность засунуть код в функцию и вызывать ее при нажатии кнопки? Оформите, пожалуйста, код нормально. Нечитаемо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В простейшем виде

Делаем i & j членами класса.

```
   private int i;
   private int j;
```

Выносим нужный код в функцию:

```
void generate() {
    i =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
    j =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
    switch (i){
        case 1:colorText.setText(R.string.Red); break;
        case 2:colorText.setText(R.string.Green); break;
        case 3:colorText.setText(R.string.Blue); break;
        case 4:colorText.setText(R.string.Yellow);
    }
    switch (j){
        case 1:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));break;
        case 2:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));break;
        case 3:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));break;
        case 4:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
    }
}
```

Функцию вызываем из обработчика третьей кнопки:

```
    buttonRegenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            generate();
        }
    });
```

Таким образом общий код становится примерно таким:

```
public class Temp {
    private int i;
    private int j;

    void create() {
        generate();

        buttontrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i==j){
                    Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "Nice!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "So bad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        buttonfalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i!=j){
                    Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "Nice!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(BoostUpYourReaction.this, "So bad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonRegenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                generate();
            }
        });
    }

    void generate() {
        i =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
        j =1+ (int)(Math.random()*4);
        switch (i){
            case 1:colorText.setText(R.string.Red); break;
            case 2:colorText.setText(R.string.Green); break;
            case 3:colorText.setText(R.string.Blue); break;
            case 4:colorText.setText(R.string.Yellow);
        }
        switch (j){
            case 1:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));break;
            case 2:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));break;
            case 3:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue));break;
            case 4:colorText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
        }
    }
}
```

Только адаптируйте этот код под свой класс и его методы

Comment: @user235380 ну добавьте вызов функции в нужное вам место.

Comment: @user235380 [Что делать с ответами на мои вопросы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)